# What novel's introduction was Shiori imitating?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

In episode 6 of the third season (or chapter 147) of *The World God Only Knows*, Shiori starts writing her story but scraps the introduction she wrote because it was imitating some other novel.

Does anyone know what novel she was referring to?

Here's a screenshot of what she wrote:
[image: Shiori writing "吾輩は女装男である。名前は桂木"]

This roughly translates to:

> I'm a cross-dressing man
>
> My name is Katsuragi

Comment: I think it is pretty natural for start with monologue in some novel and such kind of novels are a lot. For Shiori point of view , that is which she seen to Keima too.

Comment: The manga adds one more line which is not that common: "I haven't the slightest idea where I was born", I guess they left it out of the anime for copyright reasons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this is a reference to the novel ["I am a Cat"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_a_Cat) (吾輩は猫である, *Wagahai wa neko dearu*) by author [Natsume Souseki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natsume_S%C5%8Dseki). It's opening sentences are the following:

> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。

which, translated into English, is:

> I am a cat. I don't yet have a name.

The reference is more apparent if we compare the two in Japanese. The grammatical structure of the sentences is very similar:

TWGOK:

> **吾輩は** 女装男 **である。名前は** 桂木

I am a cat:

> **吾輩は** 猫 **である。名前は** まだ無い。

All the words other than the nouns are the same. The use of 吾輩 (*wagahai*) for "I", である (*dearu*) as a sentence-ending phrase would both be strange in modern writing. In addition, the general structure of the two sentences are similar enough that this is almost certainly not a coincidence.

The novel is very popular in Japan, being Natsume's first major literary work and one of his top three most read (the other two are [Kokoro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokoro) and [Botchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botchan)), and Natsume himself being in all likelihood the most important writer in Japanese history. It would not be strange at all for it to be referenced here.

Comment: And looking at the third sentence settles it. Thanks for the help!